# Why findViewById() doesn't work as getActivity().findViewById() here?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

```java
    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail,
                    container, false);
            // The detail Activity called via intent.  Inspect the intent for forecast data.
            Intent intent=getActivity().getIntent();
            TextView text=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            String b=intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
            text.setText(b);

            return rootView;
        }
    }
```

In this code when I am using

```
TextView text=(TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.text1)
```

Then my app crashes and Logcat says that

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
```

This is the XML file associated with this code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.sunshine.app.DetailActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In this code when I am using TextView text=(TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.text1)
>
> Then my app crashes and Logcat says that Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

`findViewById()` on an `Activity` starts from the root view (what is referred to as the "decor view") and traverses the tree of available widgets and containers, looking for an ID match. Hence, `findViewById()` called on an `Activity` will only find views that are part of the overall activity view hierarchy.

However, your `inflate()` call does not attach the inflated `RelativeLayout` to the activity view hierarchy. This is expected. Those views will be attached to the activity view hierarchy when the fragment itself is attached, sometime after you return from `onCreateView()`. As a result, when you call `findViewById()` on the activity *from inside `onCreateView()`*, it cannot find your `TextView`, because that `TextView` is only being managed by the fragment and is not yet part of the activity view hierarchy.

`findViewById()` on a `View` or `ViewGroup` starts from that `View` or `ViewGroup` and traverses the tree of available widgets and containers, looking for an ID match. The `RelativeLayout` has access to your `TextView`, so when you call `findViewById()` on the `RelativeLayout` that you inflate, it works.

Comment: So @CommonsWare what is the significance of this code  if(savedInstanceState == null) {
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();                                        }

Comment: @NitishChopra: That code is not in your question. If you have a separate question, use the "Ask Question" link to ask a fresh Stack Overflow question.

Comment: I have a question from your answer which I guess should be asked here only. As you said  "Those views will be attached to the activity view hierarchy when the fragment itself is attached, sometime after you return from onCreateView()"  But I read in the docs of add() method that it adds the fragment to the activity.

Comment: @NitishChopra: Calling `onCreateView()` is part of what `add()` does. `add()` cannot add views to the activity view hierarchy until `onCreateView()` returns them. Hence, in the middle of `onCreateView()`, those views are not part of the activity view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `fragment_detail.xml` layout contains your `TextView` with id `text1`, not Activity layout.